# gps speed compensation of location

Tags: android, gps

I am using GPS with Android and need to have the location compensated for speed to remove the error due to the lag of the calculation of location. My speeds of interest are in the 5 to 10 mph range as this is for a sailboat.

Here is my code:

```
        public double[] correctLocation(double pLat,double pLong,double pAngle,double pSpeed, double factor){
        double[] latLong = new double[2];
        latLong[0] = pLat + factor * pSpeed * Math.cos(pAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        latLong[1] = pLong + factor * pSpeed * Math.sin(pAngle * Math.PI / 180) / Math.cos(pLat * Math.PI / 180);
        return latLong;
    }
```

I did a test run at 25mph in a car and calculated that the factor should be 3E-6 but in trying it out at running and walking speed it is clear that a factor more like 6E-6 is needed.  I can't find any references to this through Google although I know people do this for example in the Google self driving car.  I assume others do these kind of corrections.

Can anyone help me out here?  The GPS is a Qstarz A1000XT with a MTK chipset.  There are probable things I am missing with this simplistic approach.  (I am assuming I don't need acceleration as this is a heavy boat with a 1 minute time constant for acceleration).

Comment: GPS speed is calculated as (distance/time) from previous locations to the current one, but some receivers also use doppler shift. Accuracy might vary depending on receiver quality and signal reception.

Comment: BTW consider using a Kalman Filter.

Comment: Speed is Doppler shift in this case.  All the "p" variables come from the GPS unit and are not calculations except that mps is converted to knots.

Comment: I found a bug in the way I was interpolating the position between GPS updates.  When I corrected that the 3E-6 was correct.

Comment: The factor is proportional to the time delay between computation of the location fix and the actual moment when you access this location, so it will change e.g. if you modify the output rate of the GPS receiver. Also, what unit is your pSpeed param in? m/s? mph?

Comment: pSpeed is in Knots.  I edited my ansewer and for the GPS units I am using which updates at 1 per second the delay is 1.25 seconds.  You are exactly right about it being a time delay between the reading and the reality of where you are.  Sorry for taking so long to reply.  I just finished the research on this last week.

Comment: The iphone Maps app uses such a correction, too. My app does it to, but i call it extrapolate location, since the speed will not be corrected, the location will adapted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 6E-6 was correct.  I had a couple of errors and was confused for some time on this.  I ended up testing by traveling at a spot from both directions at 25MPH and pinging the spot.  I interpolated between GPS readings so that the timing  and update rate were not a factor.  I did this 10 times.  That gave me two clusters of points and using a graphical method I adjusted the correction factor until the clusters overlapped.  An alternate method is to use the difference in latitude and longitude between the last two readings, which are 1 second apart, and apply a correction factor in seconds.  In my case that was 1.25 seconds.  Both methods produced the same result in terms of the clusters.  The speed correction was a tad closer in the scatter but not by much.  Speed on GPS is measured off the carrier and not derived from differences in position and is more accurate.